# How to correctly create performance tests for a custom logging solution?

Tags: java, logging, performance-testing, benchmarking, jmh

At work, I took an initiative to create from scratch a logging library to be used across internal services and projects.

To date, I have created a proof of concept with a custom class that `extends` `PatternLayout` and obfuscates certain fields within the output log entries.

Now the main task is to assert that performance is acceptable and my solution can handle millions of log entries without messages dropped off.

I decided to write performance tests for my custom logback, default logback layout, and Log4j2 in order to compare the output results.
I have made unit tests employing `jmh`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="FILE_APPLY_RULES" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>logs\log.txt</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="com.ingenico.epayments.logging.rule.LoggingRulesApplicator">
                <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
                <applyRules>true</applyRules>
                <loggingRules>src/test/resources/logging-rules.json</loggingRules>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC_FILE_APPLY_RULES" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPLY_RULES" />
        <queueSize>256</queueSize>
        <includeCallerData>false</includeCallerData>
        <neverBlock>true</neverBlock>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_FILE_APPLY_RULES" />
    </root>

</configuration>

@Slf4j
public class LogbackTest {

    @Test
    public void launchBenchmark() throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(this.getClass().getName() + ".*")
                .timeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
                .warmupTime(TimeValue.seconds(1))
                .warmupIterations(2)
                .measurementTime(TimeValue.seconds(1))
                .measurementIterations(2)
                .threads(2)
                .forks(1)
                .shouldFailOnError(true)
                .shouldDoGC(true)
                .addProfiler(StackProfiler.class)
                .addProfiler(HotspotRuntimeProfiler.class)
                .build();
        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.All)
    @Measurement(iterations = 200, time = 200, timeUnit = MILLISECONDS)
    @Benchmark
    public void logBenchmark() {
        log.info("{\"id\":\"12345\",\"cardData\":{\"bar\":\"bar\",\"foo\":\"foo\",\"number\":\"number\"}}");
    }

}
```

The tests are run and in the output, I see a lot of result numbers but I don't know which values should be compared and how can I assert that if I have good performance results it's not because messages have been dropped off?

Could you please give me a hint of how to prepare a valid performance test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an asynchronous `AsyncAppender` appender that can potentially drop the messages in the queue. Meanwhile the JMH benchmark expects that code in the `@Benchmark` annotated method is executed synchronously to calculate how long it takes. This won't work.

IMO you are attempting to test too many things at once e.g. the whole Logback stack. If you developed a custom layout class `LoggingRulesApplicator` start by writing a JMH bechmark just for this class.

Take a look at [existing log4j2 JMH benchmarks](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-perf/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/perf/jmh/AsyncAppenderLog4j2Benchmark.java). The setup there is simplified by using a NOOP appender which you probably should have as well.

Comment: Hi Karol, thank, I updated my question. I know that I can't get rid of the drop-offs but how can I then assert that good performance results are not because of drop-offs. I also believe that there must be a way to compare logging somehow

Comment: It feels like you are trying to write an end-to-end benchmark to prove that your solution can achieve desirable level of SLA. Either write micro benchmarks for pieces of your code e.g. just the layout, or perform a full end-to-end performance test with your application with enabled logging on a target server.